# Pandas: set group id based on identical columns and same elements in list

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

Updated!
Hi,
my data contains the names of persons and a list of cities they lived in. I want to group them together following these conditions:

- 1. `first_name` and `last_name` are identical
- 2. or (if 1. doesn't hold) their `last_name` are the same and they have lived in at least one identical `city`.

The result should be a new column indicating the group id that each person belongs to.
The DataFrame `df` looks like this:

```
>>> df
      last_name first_name                     cities
    0    Dorsey      Nancy         [Moscow, New York]
    1    Harper        Max  [Munich, Paris, Shanghai]
    2   Mueller        Max    [New York, Los Angeles]
    3    Dorsey      Nancy          [New York, Miami]
    4    Harper    Maxwell            [Munich, Miami]
```

The new dataframe `df_id` should look like this. The order of `id` is irrelevant (i.e., which group gets `id=1`), but only observations that fulfill either condition 1 or 2 should get the same `id`.

```
>>> df_id
      last_name first_name                     cities  id
    0    Dorsey      Nancy         [Moscow, New York]   1
    1    Harper        Max  [Munich, Paris, Shanghai]   2
    2   Mueller        Max    [New York, Los Angeles]   3
    3    Dorsey      Nancy          [New York, Miami]   1
    4    Harper    Maxwell            [Munich, Miami]   2
```

My current code:

```
df= df.reset_index(drop=True)
#explode lists to rows
df_exploded = df.explode('cities')
# define id_couter and dictionionary for to match index to id
id_counter = 1
id_matched = dict()

# define id function
def match_id(df):
  global id_counter

  # check if index already matched
  if df.index not in id_matched.keys():
  # get all persons with similar names (condition 1)
    select = df_expanded[(df_expanded['first_name']==df['first_name']) & df_expanded['last_name']==df['last_name'])]
    # get all persons with same last_name and city (condition 2)
    if select.empty:
      select_2 = df_expanded[(df_expanded['last_name']==df['last_name']) & (df_expanded['cities'].isin(df['cities']))]
      # create new id for this specific person
      if select_2.empty:
        id_matched[df.index] = id_counter
      # create new id for group of person and record in dictionary
      else:
        select_list = select_2.index.unique().tolist()
        for i in select_list:
          id_matched[select_list[i]] = id_counter 
    # create new id for group of person and record in dictionary
    else:
      select_list = select.index.unique().tolist()
      for i in select_list:
        id_matched[select_list[i]] = id_counter
    # set next id
    id_counter += 1

# run function
df = df.progress_apply(match_id, axis=1)

# convert dict to DataFrame
df_id_matched = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(id_matched, orient='index')
df_id_matched['id'] = df_id_matched.index

# merge back together with df to create df_id
```

Does anyone have a more efficient way to perform this task? The data set is huge and it would take several days...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your intended output and the code you tried.

Comment: Besides, your example does not meet the condition you specified, there are no persons with `identical` first and last names, who lived in the same city.

Comment: also add your expected output from the given dataframe

Comment: What should be the output for three items with the same first and last names, and the cities are intersected within each pair? (e.g. [New York, Miami], [New York, Paris], [Paris, Miami])?

Comment: In theory, you could get several groups per identical first and last name. How to handle that?

Comment: As long as they don't have the same city in common, they should be recorded with different `id`

Comment: @AnuragDabas updated accordingly

Comment: @hunter-gatherers what is the output of `id` in this case? `df=pd.DataFrame({'last_name': {0: 'Dorsey',
  1: 'Harper',
  2: 'Mueller',
  3: 'Dorsey',
  4: 'Mueller'},
 'first_name': {0: 'Nancy', 1: 'Max', 2: 'Max', 3: 'Nancy', 4: 'Max'},
 'cities': {0: ['Moscow, New York'],
  1: ['Munich', 'Paris', 'Shanghai'],
  2: ['New York', 'Los Angeles'],
  3: ['New York, Miami'],
  4: ['Munich', 'Paris', 'Shanghai']}})`

Comment: @AnuragDabas it would look like this: `df_id=pd.DataFrame({'last_name': {0: 'Dorsey',   1: 'Harper',   2: 'Mueller',   3: 'Dorsey',   4: 'Mueller'},  'first_name': {0: 'Nancy', 1: 'Max', 2: 'Max', 3: 'Nancy', 4: 'Max'},  'cities': {0: ['Moscow, New York'],   1: ['Munich', 'Paris', 'Shanghai'],   2: ['New York', 'Los Angeles'],   3: ['New York, Miami'],   4: ['Munich', 'Paris', 'Shanghai']}, 'id': {0:1, 1:2, 2:3, 3:1, 4:4}})`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#sample data was changed for lists for each cities
#like 'Moscow, New York' changed to 'Moscow', 'New York'
df_id = pd.DataFrame({'last_name':['Dorsey','Harper', 'Mueller', 'Dorsey'],
                  'first_name':['Nancy','Max', 'Max', 'Nancy'],
                   'cities':[['Moscow', 'New York'], ['Munich', 'Paris', 'Shanghai'], ['New York', 'Los Angeles'], ['New York', 'Miami']]})
```

---

```
#created default index values
df_id = df_id.reset_index(drop=True)
#explode lists to rows
df = df_id.explode('cities')

#get duplicates per 3 columns, get at least one dupe by index and sorting
s = (df.duplicated(['last_name','first_name','cities'], keep=False)
       .any(level=0)
       .sort_values(ascending=False))

#create new column with cumulative sum by inverted mask
df_id['id'] = (~s).cumsum().add(1)
print (df_id)
  last_name first_name                     cities  id
0    Dorsey      Nancy         [Moscow, New York]   1
1    Harper        Max  [Munich, Paris, Shanghai]   2
2   Mueller        Max    [New York, Los Angeles]   3
3    Dorsey      Nancy          [New York, Miami]   1
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Apparently, some `first_name` observations are missing. How would the code look like if people get the same id if either their first and last name match or (in case of missing `first_name`) their `last_name` match exactly and they lived in the same city?

Comment: @hunter-gatherers - Can you try change `df.duplicated(['last_name','first_name','cities'], keep=False)` to `df.fillna('missing').duplicated(['last_name','first_name','cities'], keep=False)` ?

Comment: Sorry, I was still editing my response while you already replied. Do you maybe know the solution also to the second part? Would be really helpful!

Comment: @hunter-gatherers - My solution working for match by both `first_name`, `last_name` or if missing some of them. Can you test if working well? If not, can you be more specific?

Comment: It doesn't work perfectly for `first_name` and `last_name` unfortunately. Several observations with different `first_name` and `last_name` have `id=1`. I have updated my answer, because I realized that the actual problem is even a bit more difficult...maybe you also know the answer to that